# How to select a table cell by other table cell name

Tags: php, regex, select, xpath

I have a structure like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Book Title</td>
    <td><a href="http://localhost/books/book-title">More Info</a></td>
    <td><a href="http://localhost/book?product=bt1">Buy Now</a></td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td>Book Title2</td>
    <td><a href="http://localhost/books/book-title2">More Info</a></td>
    <td><a href="http://localhost/book?product=bt2">Buy Now</a></td>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td>Book Title3</td>
    <td><a href="http://localhost/books/book-title3">More Info</a></td>
    <td><a href="http://localhost/book?product=bt3">Buy Now</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

How do I select the Buy now href by the book title. For example, if selected by book title "Book Title2", it will return "http://localhost/book?product=bt2".

I tried `$nodeList = $xpath->query('//*/a[contains(@href,\'product\')]');` but it only return a list of all buy now links.

Thanks!

Comment: you have to use  java script and  provide id to each td

Comment: I'm trying to web scrape data from other website using PHP

Comment: Scraping is illegal , you have to use there API to get data from there websites.

Comment: It's not illegal for educational purpose.

Comment: @AmiteshKumar Javascript isn't required. Scraping isn't necessarily illegal, and since the content is `localhost` I think it is safe to assume this isn't a live website which has TOS against it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXpath`, you should be able to use something like this:

```
$title = 'Book Title2';
echo $xpath->query('//tr[td = "' . $title . '"]/td[a = "Buy Now"]/a/@href')[0]->textContent;

// http://localhost/book?product=b2
```

See https://eval.in/637744 for a demo.